# How to properly log error object in javascript

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I am a fairly new to web development and have not given much thought to error. But today I noticed something I have to use `json.stringyfy()` to see the entire error object. Also `message` key is not shown in statement 2 but when I print `error.message` I get a message instead of `undefined`.
"message" is not even a key(check statement 4) but still logging error.message logs a value(`typeof(error.message)` is `string`) .

```
 try {
           //Some error occours
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error)) //statement 1
        console.error(error) //statement 2
        console.log(error.message) //statement 3
        console.log(Object.keys(error)) //statement 4
    }
```

statement 1 logs

```
MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: trendyApp.Markets index: name_1 dup key: { name: "murat market" }
    at D:\web projects\trendyApp\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\insert.js:51:33
    at D:\web projects\trendyApp\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection_pool.js:273:25
    at handleOperationResult (D:\web projects\trendyApp\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\server.js:363:9)
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (D:\web projects\trendyApp\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:474:9)
    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:375:28)
    at processIncomingData (D:\web projects\trendyApp\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:108:16)
    at MessageStream._write (D:\web projects\trendyApp\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:28:9)
    at writeOrBuffer (internal/streams/writable.js:358:12)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (internal/streams/writable.js:303:10)
    at TLSSocket.ondata (internal/streams/readable.js:726:22) {
  index: 0,
  code: 11000,
  keyPattern: { name: 1 },
  keyValue: { name: 'murat market' }
}
```

statement 2 logs

```
{"index":0,"code":11000,"keyPattern":{"name":1},"keyValue":{"name":"murat market"}}
```

statement 3 logs

```
E11000 duplicate key error collection: trendyApp.Markets index: name_1 dup key: { name: "murat market" }
```

I saw this behavior while I was making an express application and the error is generated by mongoose but I think this would be common throughout javascript

statement 4 logs

```
[ 'index', 'code', 'keyPattern', 'keyValue' ]
```

Comment: If you throw an error like throw new Error("This is an error"); then it is not the same as the mongoose error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "message" is not even a key(check statement 4)

It is, but `Object.keys` is designed to list [*enumerable*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) properties, and `message` is not enumerable.

In the ECMAScript specification, we see in the section on [the Error constructor](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/fundamental-objects.html#sec-error-message) that the constructor creates its message (and other properties) with the procedure:

> Perform *CreateNonEnumerableDataPropertyOrThrow*(*O*, "message", *msg*).

Other -- custom -- properties can of course be added to Error objects by JavaScript code, which explains why other properties *are* listed by `Object.keys()`.

As to the output of `console.log`: the `console` API implementation has a lot of freedom on how to display objects -- lot's of differences can be found between implementations.

To also output those non-enumerable properties, use

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(error))
```

Answer (score 1):

As @trincot said, it is not shown because of `message` is a non enumerable attribute for Error constructor, the [MongoServerError](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.2/classes/MongoServerError.html#constructor) is overriding the [MongoError](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.2/classes/MongoError.html#constructor) and actually this is overriding the JS Error object, so if you need to know what attributes you have into the error you can check the previous links to see what attributes you can check.

Also if you want to get all the attributes (included the non enumerable ones) you can use `Object.getOwnProperties(error)` to see all the attributes that the given object has.

Also you can use [Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(error)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptors) to know what is the descriptor for each attribute you've defined into the given object.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly error stack and message fields are not enumerable, below is a utility function that extracts all properties from an error object, even custom fields you assign to errors:

```js
const err = new Error('Something bad happened.');
err.metadata = { custom: { field: '1' } };


console.log(errorToPOJO(err)); // {"stack":"Error: Something bad happened.\\n    at <anonymous>:1:13","message":"Something bad happened.","metadata":{"custom":{"field":"1"}}

function errorToPOJO(error) {
  const ret = {};
  for (const properyName of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(error)) {
    ret[properyName] = error[properyName];
  }
  return ret;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if your using api

```
console.log(error.message.toString())
```